# Drag and drop gmail atachtment to files app

Tags: nautilus, drag-and-drop

For me it is an essential feature in the business environment, I cannot drag and drop a pdf from the web browser, chrome, firefox, edge, etc., in Gmail to the file explorer.
Is there any way to do it?

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Thanks in advance.